# Codes in one of my views are not processed when I access to that view

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi

My intention is to change from interface view -> switch view to process some data and send those data and change to -> test view to display the result. However, nothing in switch view seems to be processed and switch view doesn't change to test view after I hit 'submit' on userInterface.html. My guess is that the problem lies on the HttpResponseRedirect() function or anything related to url paths. Everything worked find with my other project that I worked on my computer. I'm not sure what I need to change to use Django on RaspberryPi.

At first, I found out I didn't import libraries needed for those function. After I imported them, the code was still not working.

I commented out other codes in switch view that do nothing with changing views and just focus on changing view in my switch view.

view.py

```py
def user_interface(request):
    return render(request,'zuumcoin/userInterface.html',
                  {})

def switch(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('zuumcoin:test'))

def test(request):
    return render(request,'zuumcoin/test.html',{})
```

userInterface.html

```html
....
<form action="{% url 'zuumcoin:swicht' %} method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
    ...
</form>
```

urls.py

```py
app_name='zuumcoin'
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'', views.user_interface, name='interface'),
   url(r'switch/', views.switch, name='switch'),
   url(r'test/', views.test, name='test')
]
```

I expect HttpResponseRedirect to direct me to test view instead of being stuck in switch view. If it can do that, I think I can find a way for other part of my code in my switch view to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't terminate your regexes. So the first pattern matches every path.

You should do:

```
   url(r'^$', views.user_interface...)
```

Comment: ,Don't forget to accept the answer, as a sign to future searchers that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have typo in your `userInterface.html` template. change this:

```
{% url 'zuumcoin:swicht' %}
```

to this one:

```
{% url 'zuumcoin:switch' %}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was actually just a typo when I copied the code :))